# Manage build profiles/configs for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot, sbt, java-opts

I have written application using spring boot + scala with sbt and now I need to divide build configurations for dev and prod.

**What has been done:** created configs `application.yml` and `application(-dev/prod).yml` to start application locally, on dev and prod respectively.

**What need to be done:** find a way to configure spring boot profile (dev, prod) in javaopts or directly write corresponding config, also in javaopts.

I've tried to use these opts:

```
sbt service/run -Dspring.profiles.active=...
sbt service/run -Dspring.config.location=...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to configure active profile like this:

```
sbt service/run --spring.profiles.active=...
```